# Reading lines in parallel with Keras (GPU)

Tags: machine-learning, keras, gpu

I would like to know if it is possible to read several lines from a file in parallel with my GPU in Keras. Imagine that I have a file with 50 features (i.e 50 columns) and 10k lines that I would like to process in parallel, what's the most efficient way to do it with Keras? Moreover, I don't want to train my model, since I'm already in the deployment phase of the project.

Answer (score 1):

Read the entire file, create a batch with shape `(10k, 50)` and give it to the model:

```
result = model.predict(inputData)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! When you create a batch, aren't you reading sequentially ?

Comment: What 'exactly' do you want to read in parallel? Do you mean the text file? Keras doesn't do that, and I think it's really not necessary. Your model will process a batch the best way it can, though. And if you have the GPU working properly, it will simply do it without needing extra care.

Comment: What I really would like is to have the reading of each line in parallel for a particular file. If keras handles it properly with one batch, then using the CPU in parallel and the GPU in parallel should make a difference in terms of time. No?

Comment: It depends on the type of layers you have. And if all your installations are working correctly.